# 0 arguments for overload method

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm trying to call one of my methods from main but I'm getting an error message:

> No overload for method "NextImageName" takes 0 arguments

Not sure how to fix this
On my main I called for my method "BuildingBlock.NextImage();" This is where I get an error message.

```
class BuildingBlock
{
    public static string ReplaceOnce(string word, string characters, int position)
    {
        word = word.Remove(position, characters.Length);
        word = word.Insert(position, characters);
        return word;
    }

    public static string GetLastName(string name)
    {
        string result = "";
        int posn = name.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (posn >= 0) result = name.Substring(posn + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
    {

        if (newNumber > 9)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
        }
        if (newNumber < 10)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 1));
        }
        if (newNumber == 0)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), ((filename.Length - 2) + 00));
        }
        return filename;
    }
```

Comment: Please indicate what line causes this error. How is the error message confusing you?

Comment: You need to pass parameters to your method.

Comment: None of these methods take 0 argument, the compiler is very right, consider passing some arguments to your method.

Comment: These codes doesn't get this error. Your problem is somewhere else.. Debug your code and see where you get.

Comment: When posting to SO you should include the actual line the compiler is complaining about (hint: double click the error message and it will take you there).  Also you should include the EXACT error message.  The one you typed did not include all of the details.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the method without supplying the necessary arguments to invoke it. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        int answer = GetAnswer(4); //4 is the argument
        //don't do `GetAnswer()`;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }

    public static int GetAnswer(int num)
    {
        return (num*0) + 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: num*0 will always be 0. :)

Comment: Got me there. :) didn't figure it out that you did it on purpose. Nice one.