# String Replacement parameters

Tags: c#, string

(C#)My code seems to be fine but whenever I put 0 as the second parameter it will display 
"Enemy50" when I want enemy 57 to change to enemy 00. I think theres a problem with the third if statement but not sure for to fix it.

Main

```
   string enemy57 = "enemy57";
   Console.WriteLine("The old image name is: " + enemy57);
   Console.WriteLine("New image name: " + BuildingBlock.NextImageName(enemy57, 0));
   Console.ReadLine();


class BuildingBlock
{
    public static string ReplaceOnce(string word, string characters, int position)
    {
        word = word.Remove(position, characters.Length);
        word = word.Insert(position, characters);
        return word;
    }

    public static string GetLastName(string name)
    {
        string result = "";
        int posn = name.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (posn >= 0) result = name.Substring(posn + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
    {

        if (newNumber > 9)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
        }
        if (newNumber < 10)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 1));
        }
        if (newNumber == 0)
        {
            return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
        }
        return filename;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that the almost same question you asked an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927305/0-arguments-for-overload-method

Comment: @SonerGönül No i fixed that problem but now its just a minor situation

Comment: If newNumber is zero, you will call ReplaceOnce twice.  Once because the number is less than 10 and once because it is zero.  Is this what you want?

Comment: What do you want to happen if you replace Enemy5 with 57? Enem57? Your code is inherently flawed if it doesn't look at the existing number but assumes the current string already contains the right number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that will likely do what you want.

It will:

1. Replace all final digits with the new number
2. Ensure the new number in the string is the same number of digits as the original number was in the string (or more, if needed)

Meaning that:

```
Enemy01, replace with 5, will be Enemy05
Enemy57, replace with 5, will be Enemy05
Enemy1, replace with 57, will be Enemy57
```

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    NextImageName("Enemy01", 5).Dump();
    NextImageName("Enemy57", 5).Dump();
    NextImageName("Enemy5", 57).Dump();
}

public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"\d+$");
    return re.Replace(filename, match =>
    {
        return newNumber.ToString().PadLeft(match.Length, '0');
    });
}
```

Output:

```
Enemy05
Enemy05
Enemy57
```

The regular expression

```
\d+$
```

means this:

```
  +- one or more times
  v
\d+$
^^ ^
 | |
 | +-- followed by the end of the string
 |
 digits (0-9)
```

In other words:

- One or more digits (0-9)
- Followed by the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your last call to ReplaceOnce with

```
 return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString("D2"), (filename.Length - 2));
```

The problem is because you pass the integer 0 that is converted to the string "0" which has a length of 1 char. So the ReplaceOnce method replace only the last char leaving the 5 in place.

Using the ToString [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rule D2 ensure that whatever number you pass to the method will be formatted with at least two chars.

Said that, seeing that you test for newNumber == 0 you could also write

```
 return ReplaceOnce(filename, "00", (filename.Length - 2));
```

Also, the test for zero should be executed before the test for < 10 otherwise you call the method with wrong parameters.

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{

    if (newNumber == 0)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, "00", (filename.Length - 2));
    }
    if (newNumber > 9)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
    }
    if (newNumber < 10)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 1));
    }
    // Unreachable code ???
    // return filename;
}
```

If you are sure that twh ending characters are always two digits and you want to replace the current digits with two other digits also for one digits only `newNumber` you could write

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    // ToString("D2") forces the 1-9 range to be passed as 0X no need to test 
    return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString("D2"), (filename.Length - 2));
}
```

removing all the now unnecessary tests on the digits length

Comment: Added a link to the Composite Formatting article on MSDN. see in particular [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What would i have to do change them into single digits. Such as (Enemy57, 1) turns into Enemy51, but i want it to turn into Enemy01

Comment: Apply the D2 formatting rules to every call, with the added benefit to remove all the if

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is the last if statement which checks for 0 but before you have a check for < 10 which if newnumber is 0 will enter.So its just switch that if above the other 2   or between them like this:

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    if (newNumber == 0)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
    }
    if (newNumber > 9)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 2));
    }
    if (newNumber < 10)
    {
        return ReplaceOnce(filename, newNumber.ToString(), (filename.Length - 1));
    }
    return filename;
}
```

Or if you want as an example you can also eliminate the ReplaceOnce method and do it all like this:

```
public static string NextImageName(string filename, int newNumber)
{
    if (newNumber == 0)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(filename, @"[\d+]", newNumber.ToString());
    }
    if (newNumber > 9)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(filename, @"(\d+)(?!.*\d)", newNumber.ToString());
    }
    if (newNumber < 10)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(filename, @"(\d)(?!.*\d)", newNumber.ToString());
    }
    return filename;
}
```